# I can see /bin/bash folder but why the command throws error

Tags: bash

Trying install the [Lotion](https://github.com/puneetsl/lotion) on my Ubuntu.

When running

```
./install.sh
bash: ./install.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

it throws the error.

I then cd into that folder and found the bash folder is there.

[image]

how to fix it?

Comment: How did you download this? Can you post the entire script? That ^M looks like a Windows `enter` key.

Comment: @ajgringo619 I downloaded it from the github directly by `git clone xxx` . I have figured it out and will post an answer here. thanks man

Comment: To print a ^M char you can type <ctrl+v> <ctrl+m> for example if you like to search for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching for a while, it turns out the issue is caused by the writing the script in Windows env and trying to run it in Linux env.

A super easy way to make it work is to use `dos2unix` (it can be easily installed by `sudo apt install dos2unix`)

cd into the folder where you have the code, then

`dos2unit *.sh`

then run the `./install.sh`